# google graph dot appearance on click how to remove?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, google-visualization

hello i have strange dot on interaction with google graph..
like one friend here said i can do

enableInteractivity: false,

but this is just turning off all the interaction with the graph..
i still want him on mouse over to show small div with text that it shows..

the requirments was just to remove the strange dot after click

the right dot red its a onmouse over and its working as needed

the green was click taking 2 min ago  that dont need to stay

[image: description]

this is my graph classic option

```
     var classicOptions = {
                                            title: 'Your Exposed Deal',
                                            width: 430,
                                            height: 360,
                                            // Gives each series an axis that matches the vAxes number below.
                                            series: {
                                                0: {axis: '',
                                                  },

                                     interval: {
            'interval': { 'color': '#000000', 'style':'bars', 'barWidth':0, 'lineWidth':4, 'pointSize':1, 'fillOpacity':1 },
           // 'interval': { 'color': '#000000', 'style':'bars', 'barWidth':0, 'lineWidth':4, 'pointSize':1, 'fillOpacity':1 },
           }
                                            },
                                            lineWidth: [2,2,2,1],
                                            pointSize: [2,2,2,1],
                                             hAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 0 },
                                            enableInteractivityClick: false,
                                            colors: [ 'green','red','grey'],
                                            vAxes: {
                                              // Adds titles to each axis.
                                              0: {title: 'Profit'},

                                            },
                                            hAxis: {
                                                title: 'Rate',
                                                ticks: [
         3.308,3.379,3.449,3.52,3.590,3.660,3.731        ], 
                                              legend: 'none'
                                            },
                                            vAxis: {
                                               ticks: [
         -175999.824,-131999.868,-87999.912,-43999.956,0,43999.956,87999.912,131999.868,175999.824       ] 
                                            }
                                          };

                                          function drawMaterialChart() {
                                            var materialChart = new google.charts.Line(chartDiv);
                                            materialChart.draw(data, materialOptions);

                                          }

                                          function drawClassicChart() {
                                            var classicChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(chartDiv);
                                            google.visualization.events.addListener(classicChart, 'select', selectHandler);

function selectHandler(e) {
  alert('A table row was selected');
}
```

this is the whole script

```js
          google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line', 'corechart']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

          function drawChart() {

            var button = document.getElementById('change-chart');
            var chartDiv = document.getElementById('dealchart_div');

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
           data.addColumn('number', 'X');
             data.addColumn('number', "");
             data.addColumn('number', "");
             data.addColumn('number', "");
         //    data.addColumn({type:'number', role:'interval'});
          // data.addColumn({type:'number', role:'interval'});  // interval role col.
          // data.addColumn({type:'boolean', role:'scope'});  // interval role col.
         //data.addColumn({type:'boolean', role:'scope'});  // interval role col.

           
          //  data.addColumn('number', "Average Hours of Daylight");

            data.addRows([
            
            [ 3.2032 ,175999.824,null,null ],[ 3.20672 ,174044.2704,null,null ],[ 3.21024 ,172088.7168,null,null ],[ 3.21376 ,170133.1632,null,null ],[ 3.21728 ,168177.6096,null,null ],[ 3.2208 ,166222.056,null,null ],[ 3.22432 ,164266.5024,null,null ],[ 3.22784 ,162310.9488,null,null ],[ 3.23136 ,160355.3952,null,null ],[ 3.23488 ,158399.8416,null,null ],[ 3.2384 ,156444.288,null,null ],[ 3.24192 ,154488.7344,null,null ],[ 3.24544 ,152533.1808,null,null ],[ 3.24896 ,150577.6272,null,null ],[ 3.25248 ,148622.0736,null,null ],[ 3.256 ,146666.52,null,null ],[ 3.25952 ,144710.9664,null,null ],[ 3.26304 ,142755.4128,null,null ],[ 3.26656 ,140799.8592,null,null ],[ 3.27008 ,138844.3056,null,null ],[ 3.2736 ,136888.752,null,null ],[ 3.27712 ,134933.1984,null,null ],[ 3.28064 ,132977.6448,null,null ],[ 3.28416 ,131022.0912,null,null ],[ 3.28768 ,129066.5376,null,null ],[ 3.2912 ,127110.984,null,null ],[ 3.29472 ,125155.4304,null,null ],[ 3.29824 ,123199.8768,null,null ],[ 3.30176 ,121244.3232,null,null ],[ 3.30528 ,119288.7696,null,null ],[ 3.3088 ,117333.216,null,null ],[ 3.31232 ,115377.6624,null,null ],[ 3.31584 ,113422.1088,null,null ],[ 3.31936 ,111466.5552,null,null ],[ 3.32288 ,109511.0016,null,null ],[ 3.3264 ,107555.448,null,null ],[ 3.32992 ,105599.8944,null,null ],[ 3.33344 ,103644.3408,null,null ],[ 3.33696 ,101688.7872,null,null ],[ 3.34048 ,99733.2336,null,null ],[ 3.344 ,97777.68,null,null ],[ 3.34752 ,95822.1264,null,null ],[ 3.35104 ,93866.5728,null,null ],[ 3.35456 ,91911.0192,null,null ],[ 3.35808 ,89955.4656,null,null ],[ 3.3616 ,87999.912,null,null ],[ 3.36512 ,86044.3584,null,null ],[ 3.36864 ,84088.8048,null,null ],[ 3.37216 ,82133.2512,null,null ],[ 3.37568 ,80177.6976,null,null ],[ 3.3792 ,78222.144,null,null ],[ 3.38272 ,76266.5904,null,null ],[ 3.38624 ,74311.0368,null,null ],[ 3.38976 ,72355.4832,null,null ],[ 3.39328 ,70399.9296,null,null ],[ 3.3968 ,68444.376,null,null ],[ 3.40032 ,66488.8224,null,null ],[ 3.40384 ,64533.2688,null,null ],[ 3.40736 ,62577.7152,null,null ],[ 3.41088 ,60622.1616,null,null ],[ 3.4144 ,58666.608,null,null ],[ 3.41792 ,56711.0544,null,null ],[ 3.42144 ,54755.5008,null,null ],[ 3.42496 ,52799.9472,null,null ],[ 3.42848 ,50844.3936,null,null ],[ 3.432 ,48888.84,null,null ],[ 3.43552 ,46933.2864,null,null ],[ 3.43904 ,44977.7328,null,null ],[ 3.44256 ,43022.1792,null,null ],[ 3.44608 ,41066.6256,null,null ],[ 3.4496 ,39111.072,null,null ],[ 3.45312 ,37155.5184,null,null ],[ 3.45664 ,35199.9648,null,null ],[ 3.46016 ,33244.4112,null,null ],[ 3.46368 ,31288.8576,null,null ],[ 3.4672 ,29333.304,null,null ],[ 3.47072 ,27377.7504,null,null ],[ 3.47424 ,25422.1968,null,null ],[ 3.47776 ,23466.6432,null,null ],[ 3.48128 ,21511.0896,null,null ],[ 3.4848 ,19555.536,null,null ],[ 3.48832 ,17599.9824,null,null ],[ 3.49184 ,15644.4288,null,null ],[ 3.49536 ,13688.8752,null,null ],[ 3.49888 ,11733.3216,null,null ],[ 3.5024 ,9777.7679999999,null,null ],[ 3.50592 ,7822.2143999999,null,null ],[ 3.50944 ,5866.6608,null,null ],[ 3.51296 ,3911.1072,null,null ],[ 3.51648 ,1955.5536,null,null ],[ 3.51999 ,null,null,146666.52 ],[ 3.52 ,null,null,-146666.52 ],[ 3.52352 ,null,-1955.5536,null ],[ 3.52704 ,null,-3911.1072,null ],[ 3.53056 ,null,-5866.6608,null ],[ 3.53408 ,null,-7822.2143999999,null ],[ 3.5376 ,null,-9777.7679999999,null ],[ 3.54112 ,null,-11733.3216,null ],[ 3.54464 ,null,-13688.8752,null ],[ 3.54816 ,null,-15644.4288,null ],[ 3.55168 ,null,-17599.9824,null ],[ 3.5552 ,null,-19555.536,null ],[ 3.55872 ,null,-21511.0896,null ],[ 3.56224 ,null,-23466.6432,null ],[ 3.56576 ,null,-25422.1968,null ],[ 3.56928 ,null,-27377.7504,null ],[ 3.5728 ,null,-29333.304,null ],[ 3.57632 ,null,-31288.8576,null ],[ 3.57984 ,null,-33244.4112,null ],[ 3.58336 ,null,-35199.9648,null ],[ 3.58688 ,null,-37155.5184,null ],[ 3.5904 ,null,-39111.072,null ],[ 3.59392 ,null,-41066.6256,null ],[ 3.59744 ,null,-43022.1792,null ],[ 3.60096 ,null,-44977.7328,null ],[ 3.60448 ,null,-46933.2864,null ],[ 3.608 ,null,-48888.84,null ],[ 3.61152 ,null,-50844.3936,null ],[ 3.61504 ,null,-52799.9472,null ],[ 3.61856 ,null,-54755.5008,null ],[ 3.62208 ,null,-56711.0544,null ],[ 3.6256 ,null,-58666.608,null ],[ 3.62912 ,null,-60622.1616,null ],[ 3.63264 ,null,-62577.7152,null ],[ 3.63616 ,null,-64533.2688,null ],[ 3.63968 ,null,-66488.8224,null ],[ 3.6432 ,null,-68444.376,null ],[ 3.64672 ,null,-70399.9296,null ],[ 3.65024 ,null,-72355.4832,null ],[ 3.65376 ,null,-74311.0368,null ],[ 3.65728 ,null,-76266.5904,null ],[ 3.6608 ,null,-78222.144,null ],[ 3.66432 ,null,-80177.6976,null ],[ 3.66784 ,null,-82133.2512,null ],[ 3.67136 ,null,-84088.8048,null ],[ 3.67488 ,null,-86044.3584,null ],[ 3.6784 ,null,-87999.912,null ],[ 3.68192 ,null,-89955.4656,null ],[ 3.68544 ,null,-91911.0192,null ],[ 3.68896 ,null,-93866.5728,null ],[ 3.69248 ,null,-95822.1264,null ],[ 3.696 ,null,-97777.68,null ],[ 3.69952 ,null,-99733.2336,null ],[ 3.70304 ,null,-101688.7872,null ],[ 3.70656 ,null,-103644.3408,null ],[ 3.71008 ,null,-105599.8944,null ],[ 3.7136 ,null,-107555.448,null ],[ 3.71712 ,null,-109511.0016,null ],[ 3.72064 ,null,-111466.5552,null ],[ 3.72416 ,null,-113422.1088,null ],[ 3.72768 ,null,-115377.6624,null ],[ 3.7312 ,null,-117333.216,null ],[ 3.73472 ,null,-119288.7696,null ],[ 3.73824 ,null,-121244.3232,null ],[ 3.74176 ,null,-123199.8768,null ],[ 3.74528 ,null,-125155.4304,null ],[ 3.7488 ,null,-127110.984,null ],[ 3.75232 ,null,-129066.5376,null ],[ 3.75584 ,null,-131022.0912,null ],[ 3.75936 ,null,-132977.6448,null ],[ 3.76288 ,null,-134933.1984,null ],[ 3.7664 ,null,-136888.752,null ],[ 3.76992 ,null,-138844.3056,null ],[ 3.77344 ,null,-140799.8592,null ],[ 3.77696 ,null,-142755.4128,null ],[ 3.78048 ,null,-144710.9664,null ],[ 3.784 ,null,-146666.52,null ],[ 3.78752 ,null,-148622.0736,null ],[ 3.79104 ,null,-150577.6272,null ],[ 3.79456 ,null,-152533.1808,null ],[ 3.79808 ,null,-154488.7344,null ],[ 3.8016 ,null,-156444.288,null ],[ 3.80512 ,null,-158399.8416,null ],[ 3.80864 ,null,-160355.3952,null ],[ 3.81216 ,null,-162310.9488,null ],[ 3.81568 ,null,-164266.5024,null ],[ 3.8192 ,null,-166222.056,null ],[ 3.82272 ,null,-168177.6096,null ],[ 3.82624 ,null,-170133.1632,null ],[ 3.82976 ,null,-172088.7168,null ],[ 3.83328 ,null,-174044.2704,null ],[ 3.83328 ,null,-174044.2704,null ]            //  [ $newx ,  $payyer],
            //  [new Date(2014, 1),   .4,  8.7],
            
           //[new Date(2014, 11), -.2,  4.5]
            ]);


            var classicOptions = {
           title: 'Your Exposed Deal',
           width: 430,
           height: 360,
           // Gives each series an axis that matches the vAxes number below.
           series: {
            0: {axis: '',
              },
              
          interval: {
            'interval': { 'color': '#000000', 'style':'bars', 'barWidth':0, 'lineWidth':4, 'pointSize':1, 'fillOpacity':1 },
           // 'interval': { 'color': '#000000', 'style':'bars', 'barWidth':0, 'lineWidth':4, 'pointSize':1, 'fillOpacity':1 },
           }
           },
           lineWidth: [2,2,2,1],
           pointSize: [2,2,2,1],
            hAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 0 },
           enableInteractivityClick: false,
           colors: [ 'green','red','grey'],
           vAxes: {
             // Adds titles to each axis.
             0: {title: 'Profit'},
           
           },
           hAxis: {
            title: 'Rate',
            ticks: [
   3.308,3.379,3.449,3.52,3.590,3.660,3.731   ], 
             legend: 'none'
           },
           vAxis: {
              ticks: [
   -175999.824,-131999.868,-87999.912,-43999.956,0,43999.956,87999.912,131999.868,175999.824   ] 
           }
            };

            function drawMaterialChart() {
           var materialChart = new google.charts.Line(chartDiv);
           materialChart.draw(data, materialOptions);
          
            }

            function drawClassicChart() {
           var classicChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(chartDiv);
           google.visualization.events.addListener(classicChart, 'select', selectHandler);

function selectHandler(e) {
  alert('A table row was selected');
}
           classicChart.draw(data, classicOptions);
           
            }

            drawClassicChart();

          }
```

Comment: check [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45756342/5090771), answer has been changed...

Comment: thanks its almost the client is crazy.. now its just small point !?  dont know how to remove?

Comment: Solved by whiteHat here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798824/google-graph-dot-appearance-on-click-how-to-remove